# How do I resolve an error updating pantheon-terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I get the following while trying to run updates ...

```
╭─rkm@Latitude-E6230 ~  
╰─➤  sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up pantheon-terminal (0.4.3+r1069+pkg51~daily~ubuntu16.04.1) 
...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path 
/usr/bin/io.elementary.terminal doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package pantheon-terminal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pantheon-terminal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge pantheon-terminal
```

i think the problem was in daily build, so you should disable before reinstall